"ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list!" - when accessing libimobiledevice build from the C# .NET MAUI app from Macbook Silicon chip
I can access the device UDID list from the terminal and also from the C# Console application.
But, when i try to execute the binary file from the C# .NET MAUI application, I am unable to access the device list.

ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list!

Also, when I use the custom path to the binary file in the code, like, /usr/bin/idevice_id i also get the error

ERROR: Operation not permitted


private string GetInfo()
{
    string result = "";

    var command = $"{Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Contents/MonoBundle/idevice_id")} -l";
    
    try
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo2 = process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = $"-c \"{command}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };
        Process process2 = process;
        process2.Start();
        while (!process2.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string text = ((TextReader)process2.StandardOutput).ReadToEnd();
            if (!text.Contains("Unable"))
            {
                result = text;
            }
        }

        process2.WaitForExit();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
    return result;
}

I have tried to access by custom path and also tried putting the binary file in the app content pakcages. Nothing worked.
UPDATE: I have able to solve that problem. The issue was related to App Sandbox which was enabled in Entitlements.plist file. I had to remove that.
